# Viewing the exact memory range that a linker 'uses' for a executable binary

Tags: c, x86, linker, kernel, osdev

I am doing a bit of OSdev, and I've been trying to implement memory management in my kernel. I have started off with a physical memory manager (this is a 32 bit OS). The idea is to keep a table of bits where we allocate a bit per 4K physical memory block. If the bit is '1', the block is in use and if '0', it isn't. I thought that this table should come after the kernel. So here is my kernel code (minimal):

```
#include<stdint.h> 

#define PMMAP 0x1000 //This contains information from int 15h/E820
#define BLOCK_SIZE 4096
#define SECTOR_SIZE 512
#define SECTORS_PER_BLOCK 8
#define BLOCK_SIZE_B 12
#define SECTOR_SIZE_B 9
#define SECTORS_PER_BLOCK_B 3

void  pmmngr_init(uint32_t kernelsize,uint32_t mapentrycount);
uint32_t* _physical_memory_table;

void kmain(uint32_t size,uint32_t mmapentrycount)   //This size is passed on by the bootloader, where it has a filesystem driver-ish code that determines this. The size unit is 512 bytes
{
    pmmngr_init(size,mmapentrycount);
    return;
}
struct mmap_entry {
    uint32_t  startLo;
    uint32_t  startHi;
    uint32_t  sizeLo;
    uint32_t  sizeHi;
    uint32_t  type;
    uint32_t  acpi_3_0;
  };
void  pmmngr_init(uint32_t kernelsize,uint32_t mapentrycount)
{ 
    struct mmap_entry* map_ptr= (struct mmap_entry*)PMMAP;

    _physical_memory_table = (uint32_t*)(KERNEL_P + kernelsize*SECTOR_SIZE); 

    for (uint32_t i=0;i<0x8000;i++)  //Why 0x8000? This is the size of the table (* 32 of course)
            _physical_memory_table[i] = 0xffffffff;

}
```

Initally, I make everything 0xffffffff. Then I read the Memory Map (from E820) and allocate and deallocate (later).

I compile with:

```
i686-elf-gcc kernel.c -c -g -o kernel.o --ffreestanding
i686-elf-ld kernel.o -Ttext 0x100000 -o kernel.elf
objcopy -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin
```

Note that kernel is meant to be loaded at memory space 1M.
All this was the introduction to this problem.
Here is the main issue..

Here, my *_physical_memory_table* is loaded/created after the kernel, and where it is created depends upon the size of the kernel.bin file it got from the bootloader.

Suppose the size of the kernel.bin file is ~1K, The table would be placed at 1M + 1K in memory (0x100400). Here is the core problem.. the variable **_physical_memory_table** pointer isn't really 'placed' in the 0x100000 - 0x100400 range by the linker. It belongs to the .bss section and, in my case, is placed outside this range! The pointer is present in the location where the table is created, there is an overlap, and thus, it's a bug.

So how would I solve this problem? I need to expose the 'range of control' of the kernel, i.e, the range of the kernel and all its pieces in memory, and place this table *after* that.

So what do I do? (I'm guessing something with the linker script)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a custom linker script for a kernel. In the script would would have the normal sections for .text, .rodata, .data, .bss and a few others. The custom is to define symbols for each section for the start and end for the current address in the linking process, e.g. `_text_start = .` and `_text_end = .` around the members in the .text section.

In your C code you can then declare variables:

```
extern void *_text_start[], *_text_end[];
```

Those will then have the addresses filled in by the linker and will tell you where each section of your kernel starts and ends. Often you also have a _end symbol that's after all sections. Usually that is identical to _bss_end, with .bss being the last section.

Your kernel would place _physical_memory_table after _end to avoid any overlaps with itself.

Although most people include a fixed initial _physical_memory_table in their .data or .bss sections that simply maps 4GB of memory 1:1. Once the MMU is up and running and you switched to kernel_start() a proper, fine grained memory table can be setup more easily with C code.

In my kernel I also include 64KB of unused memory in the .bss section that is used to prime the memory management. So right from the start there are 64KB of memory available for allocations. The code that parses the memory map can then allocate data structures from that pool before it adds free memory regions to the allocator.

Comment: So this would not use the size of the kernel.bin file in any way.. (The size I calculate from the bootloader)

Comment: "Although most people include a fixed initial _physical_memory_table in their .data or .bss sections that simply maps 4GB of memory 1:1. Once the MMU is up and running and you switched to kernel_start() a proper, fine grained memory table can be setup more easily with C code." -What does this 1:1 mean?

Comment: Why `extern void *foo[]`?  It's not an array of `void*`; it's not really an array at all, you just want symbols whose address is the address you want.  The C type shouldn't include "pointer" because that implies there is a pointer *stored in memory*.  There isn't; we just need the symbol address.  It makes more sense IMO to use `extern char _text_start[]` as suggested in [Is there a way to find addresses of the code sections (.data, .text, etc) at runtime?](//stackoverflow.com/a/60028779)

Comment: @PeterCordes so the is no actual need to know the size of the kernel.bin file?

Comment: @SuraajKS 1:1 means that virtual 0 will map to physical 0. virtual 0x100000 maps to physical 0x100000. If the kernel is later supposed to run in higher half you would also map 0x8000000 (or 0xC000000) to 0x0 repeating the first GB of physical memory again. Similar for 64bit setups.

Comment: @PeterCordes `char` works just as well as `void *` as will any other type. In both case the `[]` at the end makes it degrade to a pointer with a value of the symbol. The type of it is irrelevant for the use case. Ideally I would want it to be `void` because the address should not be used for anything but it's own value. As `char []` you could accidentally write `printf("start = %s\n", _text_start)` and get no error or warning.

Comment: Ah... In my case I do this in my bootloader ( these two mappings).... and the kernel just 'loads' at 0xC0000000

Comment: @SuraajKS Correct. The actual size of the bin file doesn't factor into it.

Comment: Just had another flashback to my own problems: What about an initramfs? The multiboot protocol used by e.g. grub allows loading any number of modules after the kernel and will tell the kernel about where they end up. If the kernel simply puts stuff after itself it might overwrite the initramfs or other modules loaded by the bootloader. Which is why I have space reserved in my .bss for initial allocations so I can parse the memory map and bootloader info. Grub knows elf so it leaves a gap between the kernel and modules the size of the .bss section.

Comment: Yes, using `char []` allows you to write `printf("start = %s\n", _text_start)`, that's exactly why I suggested it so you can treat the symbol name as a value.  Why do you think that deserves a warning?

Comment: The printf will take the address _text_start, dereference it and print the byte sequence at that location. The binary code of a kernel hardly ever makes for a printable string. It's a value, not a pointer to a string (or char array). The right type would be `void *`, which can't be dereferenced, but that isn't achievable with the `[]` trick as you can't have an array of void. Anyway, minor detail. Use whatever type you like since any correct use of the value will not care as long as you use it consistently.